# Auto-renewable subscription receipt date format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter, subscription

I'm struggling to figure out the formatting for the following date:

`2011-05-24 19:02:32 Etc/GMT`

This date is returned from Apple's receipt validation service and I need to turn it into a NSDate for some comparison operations.  The real trouble is related to the timezone.

Here's some code I've already written:

```
        NSDictionary *receiptData = [info valueForKey:@"expires_date"];

        NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        [f setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
        [f setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
        [f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss vvvv"];

        NSLog(@"%@", [f stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);

        NSDate *subPurchaseDate = [f dateFromString:[receiptData valueForKey:@"original_purchase_date"]];

        [f release];
```

I've tried all combinations of 'v's and 'Z's that I can think of.  Any insight?

Comment: Did you have any joy with this? I was about to post the same question when I came across your one.

Comment: Does anyone else thing it strange that Apple returns this string but the Apple frameworks can't parse it?

Comment: No, but that's largely because I've been working with Apple technology for a few years now.  You get used to the pain after a while.

Comment: Almost 9 years later, and this is still just as painful as it was then.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By looking at the date format documentation I got the correct format, is works well for me:

```
        NSDateFormatter * formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV";

        NSDate * purchaseDate = [formatter dateFromString:latestTransaction[@"original_purchase_date"]];
        NSDate * expirationDate = [formatter dateFromString:latestTransaction[@"expires_date"]];
```

No need to set the time zone on the formatter since it's embedded in the string. 
**Manipulating the date string to parse it is not a good idea.**

Source: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: This works i wouldn't remove the timezone like the accepted answer does. You should switch the day and month: yyyy-dd-MM => yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: For some reason, this format does not work for customers who purchase in Israel :O

Comment: I'm not sure what the string is in the receipt, but `[formatter dateFromString:latestTransaction[@"expires_date"]];` returned `NULL` for the customer who purchased in Israel. Worked great in US.

Comment: Interesting. If you can post the string we can figure out if it's localized. Israel time is like Europe - "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: > "No need to set the time zone on the formatter since it's embedded in the string."  My experience suggests that setting the time zone on the formatter is crucial - otherwise it overrides what is embedded in the string. At least when using Swift in iOS 13.4.1 & iOS 13.5.

Answer (score 4):

After doing some more research, the code I'm using here works, but is suspect;

```
   NSString *purchaseDateString = [@"2011-05-24 19:02:32 Etc/GMT" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" Etc/GMT" withString:@""];
   NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   NSLocale *POSIXLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease];
   [formatter setLocale:POSIXLocale];
   [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
   [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

   NSDate *purchaseDate = [formatter dateFromString:purchaseDateString];
```

I don't like the assumptions I am making about the incoming date string and so I am assuming this code may break for other stores (I'm testing against the UK one). So although this kind of works for my own situation, I'd really like to see a more robust solution that actually parses the timezone string correctly as per the original question.

I can't quite believe Apple have used a deprecated timezone (all the Etc/* ones are officially deprecated) in these important date strings!

EDIT:

I note you are using

```
NSDictionary *receiptData = [info valueForKey:@"expires_date"];
```

This is not actually a string [according to the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW5) it should be "The expiration date of the subscription receipt, expressed as the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT"

However the question is still valid as you have to use the purchase_date field when working with restored subscriptions and this field is in the text format you have described.

Comment: I ended up doing the same find/replace in my code but I replaced the 'Etc/GMT' with 'GMT' to make my life a bit easier.  Additionally, I had the same reservations you had about using this solution, but frankly I can't find anything else that would work.  Thanks for confirming my solution.

Comment: I'd add a check that the string ends with "Etc/GMT", and do some kind of logging if it's not true (pop up a MFMailComposeViewController and ask the user to send a bug report?). It's a bit messy, but oh well.

Comment: Why remove the Etc/GMT? It's a legit time zone, so it seems. E.g. http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php

Comment: @Tudorizer, primarily because NSDateFormatter doesn't appear to be able to parse it.

Comment: It can definitely parse it, you just need to use the correct format. Look at my answer below

Answer (score 1):

The following code can be used to parse [RFC 3339 dates found in App Store receipts](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html):

```swift
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

let date = formatter.date(from: "2020-06-17 10:59:33 Etc/GMT")
```

Note that it *is* necessary to set the `timeZone` as well as the `locale`. Also setting `locale` before `dateFormat` is important according to [Technical Q&A QA1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

[Apple recommends](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) using the newer `ISO8601DateFormatter` API on iOS 10+ and macOS 10.12+.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do on Swift 3 to convert the date from an auto-renewable date from a receipt.

```
let expirationDate = "2017-08-16 23:10:35 Etc/GMT"
let receiptDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"
let theDateFormat = DateFormatter.Style.medium
let theTimeFormat = DateFormatter.Style.medium
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = receiptDateFormat
let firstDate = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDate)
dateFormatter.dateStyle = theDateFormat
dateFormatter.timeStyle = theTimeFormat

let result = dateFormatter.string(from: firstDate!)
```